# jQuery formValidation not submitting form on pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, formvalidation-plugin

I am Using Jquery `formValidation` plugin to validate my form. everything works fine when i click on submit button it submits the form after validation. But when i hit Enter key on keyboard it still validate form and dont submit form and form values are gone. Do i need to write code here ? i guess it's working but not listening enter key being pressed ?

```
$('#login_form').formValidation({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        email: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The email address is required'
                },
                emailAddress: {
                    message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                }
            }
        },
        password: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The password is required'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I encountered about a year ago on version 0.6.2 so i'm not sure if they fixed it by now or not, what I did was basically disable the "enter" key from being able to submit my form, this is the code I used:

```
$('#form-login').on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (code === 13) {               
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Too bad nobody replied to you for a month, I just came across this again in my own project so I saw your question :) Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I had the same problem, but I adapted your solution for the enter to send the form. After the e.preventDefault () command; simulate a click event on the submit button something like $ ('#submitButton').Click ();

Answer (score 0):

It's a late reply, but I faced this problem just recently. 
Look at how your submit button is formatted.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
```

If either the attribute name or id is the word submit you may encounter this error. Just change your input type and it will probably work

```
<input type="submit" name="confirm" id="confirm" value="submit"/>
```